# Algorithm for tracking the movement of nodes in a directed adjacency list

Tags: algorithms, trees

I have a directed adjacency list of node's. The structure of a node is

```
Node {
  id: integer;
  order: integer;
  parentId: integer | null;
}
```

and the following nodes for the sake of example.

```
[
{id: 1, order: 1, parentId: null},
{id: 2, order: 1, parentId: 1},
{id: 3, order: 2, parentId: 1},
{id: 4, order: 1, parentId: 2},
{id: 5, order: 2, parentId: 2},
{id: 6, order: 3, parentId: 2},
{id: 7, order: 4, parentId: 2},
{id: 8, order: 1, parentId: 3},
{id: 9, order: 5, parentId: 2},
{id: 10, order: 3, parentId: 1}
]
```

I need an algorithm that can

- reorder node(s) within the same level on the hierarchy
- move node(s) to a different level and inserted into an arbitrary order.

```
algorithm moveNodes
   input
   number[] nodes: Array of 1 to n node IDs. 

   integer destinationParentId: The new parent for each node 
 in the nodes array.

   integer position: The starting order the nodes will be 
 inserted into. 

Output
 An array of operations describing the updates required 
 to move the nodes in the 
 nodes  input param to be a child of destinationParentId 
 starting at position. Nodes are inserted
in the order they appear in the nodes param.
```

Assume the node IDs passed to the moveNodes nodes param all have the same parentId, so nodes from different levels won't be moved in the same operation.

Also, assume that the function won't be called in a way that would nest a node inside itself or one of its descendant nodes.

## Other requirements

- No nodes can have both the same parentId and order.
- There can't be any gaps in the order for siblings.

## Examples

(Assume changes are independent / don't persist between function runs)

`moveNodes(nodes: [6, 7], destinationParentId: 2, order: 1)`

should return

```
[
{id: 4, nextOrder: 3},
{id: 5, nextOrder: 4},
{id: 6, nextOrder: 1},
{id: 7, nextOrder: 2}
]
```

(so we are going [4, 5, 6, 7, 9] -> [6, 7, 4, 5, 9])

`moveNodes(nodes: [2,3], destinationParentId: 2, order: 1)`

should return

```
[
{id: 2, nextParentId: 2},
{id: 3, nextParentId: 2},
{id: 10, nextOrder: 1},
{id: 4, nextOrder: 3},
{id: 5, nextOrder: 4},
{id: 6, nextOrder: 5},
{id: 7, nextOrder: 6},
{id: 9, nextOrder: 7}
]
```

(so we are going
[2, 3, 10] -> [10] and
[4, 5, 6, 7, 9] -> [2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9])

Comment: I don't understand what "starting order" means.  I don't understand the intended relationship between "order" vs "position".  What do you mean by "updates"?  I'm not sure what kind of updates are allowed to appear in the output.

Comment: @D.W. I used order and position interchangeably, they mean the same thing in this context. Regarding updates, it would be the minimum info required to get the list of objects from one state another (before the nodes are moved, to after the nodes are moved). So if when moving a node, if it's order needs to changed, it would be in the output with a "nextOrder" attribute. If it's parentId changes, it would be in the outwith with a "nextParentId". If both it's order and parentId changes, it would be in the output with both a "nextOrder" and a "nextParentId".